# Is inelastic collision formula wrong?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, energy-conservation, inertial-frames, collision

At school, I was taught that when two object collide and merge into one, and due to the conservation of momentum we will have this equation: *m1.v1 + m2.v2 = (m1 + m2).v3* with:

- m1, m2 are the two object's masses
- v1, v2 are their initial velocities
- v3 is the final velocity

Assuming two objects are moving toward each other and they have different masses.

So in the object 1 perspective, we have: *m2.(v1 + v2) = (m1 + m2).v3* (1)

And so on with the 2nd object's perspective: *m1.(v1 + v2) = (m1 + m2).v3* (2)

Due to the conservation of momentum (1) and (2) should be equal. However, since their masses are different, (1)≠(2).

One more thing, If (1)=(2), the final velocity (v3) in each perspective will be different and it is obviously non-sense!

So is the formula wrong or I'm wrong?

Comment: Please do not post formulae as text, but use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/143136) instead.

Comment: *"One more thing, If (1)=(2), the final velocity (v3) in each perspective will be different and it is obviously non-sense!"* Why? You have two different frames, and the resulting "fused" object has different velocities in them. That's not non-sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does indeed work out.  However, we have to be careful with how we define "from an object's perspective."  You're defining different frames, and conversions between frames *can* change the values of velocities.

The key question is what happens to the frames at the collision.  If the frame keeps going along on the path m1 or m2 would have taken, then you will find that the velocities in the two frames are equivalent.  However, if you stay "from the object's perspective," and thus stay fused with it, you have an accelerating frame.  These behave very differently, and can change the value of a velocity from the expected value.

The easiest story is if we let the frames keep moving along the path of the object if no collision occurred.  We'll define frame f1 to be a frame that following object 1's original trajectory, and f2 to be the frame that followings object 2's original trajectory.  Thus we can say $v_{1,f1}=0$ and $v_{2,f2}=0$.  Including the subscripts in these velocities is important because it lets us untangle the issue you saw.

Thus we now write your two equations as
$$m_1v_{1,f1} + m_2v_{2,f1} = (m_1+m_2)v_{3,f1}$$
$$m_1v_{1,f2} + m_2v_{2,f2} = (m_1+m_2)v_{3,f2}$$

As you noticed, the objects are at rest in the frame that follows their trajectory, so this simplifies to
$$m_2v_{2,f1} = (m_1+m_2)v_{3,f1}$$
$$m_1v_{1,f2} = (m_1+m_2)v_{3,f2}$$

To get to the equations you wrote, we have to bring in one more frame, f0.  This is the frame you started with in your initial problem, where both objects are moving.  We can say $v_{2,f1} = v_{2,f0} - v_{1, f0}$, showing that the velocity in the f1 frame is always that of the velocity in the f0 frame minus the velocity of object 1.  Likewise $v_{1,f2} = v_{1,f0} - v_{2, f0}$.  Plugging these in, we finally arrive at the equations (1) and (2) that you started with, but with a bit more formalism in place to help untangle things
$$m_2(v_{2,f0} - v_{1, f0}) = (m_1+m_2)v_{3,f1}$$
$$m_1(v_{1,f0} - v_{2, f0}) = (m_1+m_2)v_{3,f2}$$

Now you'll note that I have a minus sign here, when you had a plus.  That's probably most of the confusion.  You actually were solving the problem with respect to a frame that took off in the *opposite* direction of the objects.  But it would still have worked.

The bigger issue is that you notice we can't just set these two equatiosn equal.  $v_{3,f1}$ and $v_{3,f2}$ are two different things.  They are certainly related, but they're not the same.  They also aren't exactly opposites. $v_{3,f1} \neq v_{3,f2}$ unless the masses are the same.  What we can do, however, is subtract the two equations from eachother

$$m_2(v_{2,f0} - v_{1, f0}) - m_1(v_{1,f0} - v_{2, f0}) = (m_1+m_2)(v_{3,f1}- v_{3,f2})$$

$$(m_1+m_2)(v_{2,f0} - v_{1, f0}) - (m_1+m_2)(v_{3,f1}- v_{3,f2})$$
$$v_{2,f0} - v_{1, f0} = v_{3,f1}- v_{3,f2}$

So what did we just arrive at?  The differences between the final combined velocity in f1 and f2 is equal to the difference between the initial velocities in f0.  This is intuitively expected, as the difference between f1 and f2 is indeed a velocity shift accounting for the velocities of both particles.

This non-answer of sorts tells us something important: solving this problem in different frames did not change the story any.  The results will be consistent with each other.  You can solve this system in any frame which makes sense to you, and the result will be the same (after you convert the results back into the final frame of your choosing).